# Is there a way to retain the undo list in Emacs after reverting a buffer from file?

Tags: emacs, elisp, undo

How can I make Emacs retain its undo history for my buffer after doing revert-buffer or using auto-revert-mode?

In Vim, if a file that is open in a buffer is changed on disc, Vim prompts me to reload the file. I can then simply click 'u' to undo the reload if I so wish and even go back further from then. Emacs seems to trash all the undo information the moment I revert the buffer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the obvious approach would be a function which kills the current buffer content, and then calls `insert-file` to read in the current content from the file.

If the changes to the file included changes to the character encoding, there might be problems? I haven't tested that.

Here's my current attempt. It's a little hairy IMO, but it works okay.

```
;; Allow buffer reverts to be undone
(defun my-revert-buffer (&optional ignore-auto noconfirm preserve-modes)
  "Revert buffer from file in an undo-able manner."
  (interactive)
  (when (buffer-file-name)
    ;; Based upon `delphi-save-state':
    ;; Ensure that any buffer modifications do not have any side
    ;; effects beyond the actual content changes.
    (let ((buffer-read-only nil)
          (inhibit-read-only t)
          (before-change-functions nil)
          (after-change-functions nil))
      (unwind-protect
          (progn
            ;; Prevent triggering `ask-user-about-supersession-threat'
            (set-visited-file-modtime)
            ;; Kill buffer contents and insert from associated file.
            (widen)
            (kill-region (point-min) (point-max))
            (insert-file-contents (buffer-file-name))
            ;; Mark buffer as unmodified.
            (set-buffer-modified-p nil))))))

(defadvice ask-user-about-supersession-threat
  (around my-supersession-revert-buffer)
  "Use my-revert-buffer in place of revert-buffer."
  (let ((real-revert-buffer (symbol-function 'revert-buffer)))
    (fset 'revert-buffer 'my-revert-buffer)
    ;; Note that `ask-user-about-supersession-threat' calls
    ;; (signal 'file-supersession ...), so we need to handle
    ;; the error in order to restore revert-buffer.
    (unwind-protect
        ad-do-it
      (fset 'revert-buffer real-revert-buffer))))

(ad-activate 'ask-user-about-supersession-threat)
```

Annoyingly, I've only just noticed all the relevant-looking information in the `revert-buffer` docs, so there's probably a *much* simpler way to do this.

> If the value of `revert-buffer-function` is non-nil, it is called to
>   do all the work for this command.  Otherwise, the hooks
>   `before-revert-hook` and `after-revert-hook` are run at the beginning
>   and the end, and if `revert-buffer-insert-file-contents-function` is
>   non-nil, it is called instead of rereading visited file contents.

Comment: I think this is a very good approach. I'm going to have a go at tweaking that myself. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. I figured out solutions to some problems with that code, and have updated the answer: it now sets the updated buffer as unmodified, and I found that `(set-visited-file-modtime)` was the way to stop that from being a problem. This means that if you undo the revert, it no longer asks you the question again if you then try to re-modify the file, which is definitely more in keeping with the original functionality. If you come up with an improved solution, please do post a new answer here.

Answer (score 10):

Emacs allows you to set revert-buffer-function to override the behaviour. Here's a revert-buffer implementation that keeps the history.

```
;; emacs doesn't actually save undo history with revert-buffer
;; see http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gnu-emacs/2011-04/msg00151.html
;; fix that.
(defun revert-buffer-keep-history (&optional IGNORE-AUTO NOCONFIRM PRESERVE-MODES)
  (interactive)

  ;; tell Emacs the modtime is fine, so we can edit the buffer
  (clear-visited-file-modtime)

  ;; insert the current contents of the file on disk
  (widen)
  (delete-region (point-min) (point-max))
  (insert-file-contents (buffer-file-name))

  ;; mark the buffer as not modified
  (not-modified)
  (set-visited-file-modtime))

(setq revert-buffer-function 'revert-buffer-keep-history)
```

Comment: Would be great if the point location was preserved as well ;)

Comment: is it similiar to approach on https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/RevertBuffer under `Reverting but keeping undo` section ?

Comment: This approach leads cursor to jump to the top of the page, is it possible to prevent it?

Answer (score 5):

The upcoming Emacs-24.4 does what you want by default.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the *before-hook* to save the previous buffer-content to the kill-ring:

```
(add-hook 'before-revert-hook  (lambda () (kill-ring-save (point-min) (point-max))))
```